# arithmetic operation not working

Tags: c#, .net

```
   float percentrelation = Individualrelatonshipdegree / relationshipdegree * 100;
```

This simple operation returns 0 while the value in Individualrelationshipdegree variable is 19 and in the relationshipdegree is 35. but it still returns 0. don't understand this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with ASP.NET - tag removed. Please only use tags which are really meaningful to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing integer division. try

```
float percentrelation = 
    1.0f * Individualrelatonshipdegree / relationshipdegree * 100;
```

Comment: I wish I have one € per new coder I saw stumbling upon this and asking for help... :-)

Comment: @user1698985 Since expression is evaluated from left to right `1.0f*Individualrelatonshipdegree` will be a float and all result will be converted to float

Comment: @PhiLho don't you mean €1.0f ? :P

Comment: @Rotem Nope, €1.0m.  Use `decimal` for monetary values.  (Floating point rounding errors are another €1.0, right?)

Answer (score 4):

Just look at the calculation order. You want to div 19 by 35. So it's 0. And then multiply 0 and 100. It's also 0. 
So you can try make first variable float for this expression by type casting:

```
float percentrelation = (float)Individualrelatonshipdegree / relationshipdegree * 100;
```

**UPD** Need to explain type casting moment. The calculation order is from left to right. And we have a rule that in operation with integer(int, byte, long long etc.) and float(float, double etc.) operands they both are type casted to float type. That's why we need just one type casting on first operand. And that's why another answer with 1.0f * `your expression` also works fine. Just two little different ways.

Comment: hhh... Nice Explanation. never thought this way. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are the two variables integers? If yes, you might want to cast them first.

```
float percentrelation = (float) Individualrelatonshipdegree / (float) relationshipdegree * 100;
```

Also, note that float is not very precise. Consider using decimal isntead.

Comment: It is enough to only cast one of them.

Comment: True. For the OP, float / int is still float, and similarly a decimal / int will be a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [float (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)

Bacially you are missing `.F`

eg. `float x = 2.5F/3.5;`